# Marketing Cloud Journey Unsubscription Sources

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, unsubscribe

I have a journey which sends an email. Within that email there is an unsubscribe link in the footer that leads to a cloud page on which a user can unsubscribe. This updates both a data extension and data in salesforce, it works fine.

When I look at the journey analytics there is an Unsubscribe tab, the contacts listed there haven't clicked our unsubscribe in footer. Can anyone advise what is the source of these unsubscribes?

Also to add a lot of them appear to happen within seconds of each other making me suspect it may be a email client or something like that, maybe a domain filter (are lot are the same domain and appear to be work email addresses, I'm not overly familiar with the technicalities around this ) automatically unsubscribing them, how would it do that if that is the case? How do we know that is the trigger for unsubscribe?

I did also suspect list-unsubscribe header in email being used but not sure how to verify that. It may be the case for some that aren't part of the block at the same time, again is there a way to identify/confirm this.

I have ran a query on _unsubscribe data view in query studio but can't see any more info there that would point to the exact reason. Is there a way to get more info?

Ideally we want to capture these in some way so we can update their subscription info in salesforce, as we use this info in journeys to decide if emails are sent. Presumably if they unsubscribe this way they won't get anymore emails anyway?

Comment: These are most probably list-unsubscribe header unsubscribes: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_one_click_header_unsubscribe.htm&type=5

Comment: But is there any way of knowing. Is it flagged anywhere that they are list unsubscribes